# how to make dynamic OpenCV webcam video streaming in c++

Tags: opencv, video, feed, live

The below is used to get the live video feed from the 4 webcam. But all the code i have written is limited only for four camera. I want to make this code dynamic that is. If two camera is connected it should only display two windows, if 3 are connected it should show 3 window. I am getting the number of camera attached to the System. I want to implement the code for that number of camera. Can someone please point me in right direction.

```
using namespace cv;

int main(){

//Create matrix to store image
Mat image;
Mat image1;
Mat image2;
Mat image3;

//Mat image1;
//initailize capture
videoInput VI;
int numDevices = VI.listDevices(); //getting number of camera attached to system                     dynamically.   
VideoCapture cap;
VideoCapture cap1;
VideoCapture cap2;
VideoCapture cap3;

bool x = false;
//VideoCapture cap1;
cap.open(0);
cap1.open(1);
cap2.open(2);
cap3.open(3);

namedWindow("Camera 1",1);
namedWindow("Camera 2",1);
namedWindow("Camera 3",1);
namedWindow("Camera 4",1);

while(1){
    //copy webcam stream to image
    cap >> image;
    cap1 >> image1;
    cap2 >> image2;
    cap3 >> image3;
    cap4 >> image4;
    //cap1 >> image1;
    imshow("Camera 1",image);
    imshow("Camera 2",image1);
    imshow("Camera 3",image2);
    imshow("Camera 4",image3);

    //imshow("Camera 2",image1);
    //delay 33ms
    waitKey(33);
}
 }
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged MFC? This seems to be completely irrelevant and unrelated.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to create application in MFC so i have tagged it to MFC. According to you what should be the tag ?

Answer (score 0):

The link to a webcam is usually a direct http link. So, just create a static html file that has individual frame for each webcam link, arrange these frames the way that you want to view by using html code. Launch this static html page in your embedded browser of your application.